# How to detect certain symbols in a string and use them to mark special words?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I would like to detect certain symbols in a string and use them to mark special words.

Here's and example:

> Symbols to mark special words:
> Action - ѧ; Job - Ꝭ;
> Location - լ;
> Number - ₦;
>
> Example:
> ₦7₦ hundred ꝬclerkꝬs have said “լOhioլ is ѧdyingѧ”. We are ₦100₦% sure about this.

each special word needs to be put in a corresponding array.

Haven't really made anything like this in the past.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: -> [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This LINQ can probably be optimized for better complexity but here is a way to put it into a Dictionary

```cs
string s = "₦7₦ hundred ꝬclerkꝬs have said “լOhioլ is ѧdyingѧ”. We are ₦100₦% sure about this.";
char[] special = { '₦', 'Ꝭ', 'լ', 'ѧ' };
string[] words = s.Split(" ");

Dictionary<char, string[]> wordDict = special
    .ToDictionary(
        c => c,
        c => words
            .Where(w => Regex.IsMatch(w, $"{c}.+{c}")) //match on flagged char + any length of characters + flagged char
            .Select(w => w.Split(c)[1]) //throw out fluff at beginning and end
            .ToArray()
    );

foreach (KeyValuePair<char, string[]> kv in wordDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} - {string.Join(", ", kv.Value)}");
}

/*
Outputs:
₦ - 7, 100
Ꝭ - clerk
լ - Ohio
ѧ - dying
*/
```

Big idea is to use regex to match words from the sentence (we split the string on `" "` to get the words), as you can imagine that the special chars "escape" the words. Iterating over the `special` array allows us to dynamically create the regex patterns with some string interpolation, where the special chars are at the ends while it accepts any number of chars in-between, as denoted by `.+` in the pattern

I chose to use Dictionary to allow for easy lookups, that way if you want just one of these arrays then you can do `wordDict[₦]` or any other key from the special chars. Naturally, you can make it `Dictionary<char, List<string>>` by swapping out `.ToArray()` with `.ToList()` within the value selector lambda

Edit: updating with the Select query to "encrypt" strings into something like "____"

```cs
Dictionary<char, string[]> wordDict = special
    .ToDictionary(
        c => c,
        c => words
            .Where(w => Regex.IsMatch(w, $"{c}.+{c}")) //match on flagged char + any length of characters + flagged char
            .Select(w => new string('_', w.Split(c)[1].Length))
            .ToArray()
    );
```

All that's been altered is the `.Select()` query which maps the output strings, in this case we are creating new strings with '_' repeated n times, where n = length of the word trimmed of its special char escape pattern

Comment: Thx, this will do, but i have another question.

How can i replace those marked words with a certain symbol ("_" for example) and make them match the length of the word? So it will output something like this:

" _ hundred _____s have said “_____ is _____”. We are___% sure about this."

Comment: @SolidP the perfect line to do this on `.Select(w => w.Split(c)[1])` as this line is mapping the output strings. I wrote it this specific way in order to trim the special symbol from the beginning and end. Yours would probably look something like `.Select(w => new string('_', w.Split(c)[1].Length))` meaning, create a new string that is '_' repeated as many times as the length of the trimmed word

Comment: Updated solution with the answer to your comment